# Xsd documentation value

Tags: c#, xsd, annotations, element

how can I create xsd documentation programatically?
Example:

```
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Documentation</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

I used:

```
 XmlSchemaElement element = new XmlSchemaElement();
    XmlSchemaAnnotation annotation = new XmlSchemaAnnotation();
    XmlSchemaDocumentation doc = new XmlSchemaDocumentation();

    //doc.Value = "Documentation"; ??
    annotation.Items.Add(doc);
    element.Annotation = annotation;
```

but how do I set documentation value? There is no such property in XmlSchemaDocumentation type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a small thing, like

```
annotation.Items.Add(doc);
doc.Markup = TextToNodeArray("Your text you need");
```

could you try this and see what if this helps any?

refer otherwise to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemadocumentation.aspx which should give you pretty nice examples otherwise how to work with it.

Comment: Thanks! Great, I found only http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256112.aspx so it doesnt helps.